# XmlDocument caching memory usage

Tags: .net, xml, caching, xmldocument

We are seeing very high memory usage in .NET web applications which use XmlDocument.
A small (~5MB) XML document is loaded into an XmlDocument object and stored in HttpContext.Cache for easy querying and XSLT transformation on each page load. The XML is modified on disk periodically so a cache has a dependency on the file.

Such an application appears to be using hundreds of megabytes of RAM.

I have experimented with requesting garbage collection on each request start, and this keeps the RAM usage far lower but I cannot imagine this is good practise.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how we can achieve the same goal but with lower RAM usage?

Comment: I'm suspicious of the "appears to be using" in the question. If you use a dummy (as close to Zero MB as you can get) XML document, does your memory usage drop accordingly? Is the memory hog the XML Document or XSLT Transform?

Comment: Does the memory usage continue to grow if you leave it alone or does it stablise over time?

Comment: Binary Worrier - I say "appears" because having used several techniques to watch the memory usage increase I couldn't give you an exact figure but it definitely rises. I believe it is the XML Document and not the transform.
AnthonyWJones - It stablises when idle between page loads, and even with continuous traffic it does level out over time i.e. it does not continue to grow forever.

Comment: In that case this may simply be normal, if your memory does not have other demands on it .NET may not necessarily be too bothered about releasing memory quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My two cents . . .

I'd be worried if memory use was exponential based on the size of the XML document. e.g. 1mb XML file memory settles at 10mb, 2mb flattens out at 30mb, etc.

Also, consider the cost of the XML file not so much on byte size, but on the cost of each node. If your 5mb XML doc had say two data nodes, then the in-memory representation of the document wouldn't be much greater than 5mb (actually it could be far less, considering that binary data in XML will be double what it will be in memory).

`*`If your XML doc is utf-8, and you've two large text nodes, then the in-memory representation could be 10mb (the text could be stored in .net strings, which are Unicode, and will be twice the width of standard English language UTF-8 text).

If the XML document is comprised of lots of discreet string values, then every node is an object, every node name is an object, every node value is an object. So assuming references are 4 bytes, that's (at least) an extra 12 bytes per node.

Now, assuming you've lots of nodes, and assume your average length of node name+value is 20 characters, then the reference overhead of a 5mb file is 3mb, plus a possible extra 100% for utf-8 to Unicode conversion, it takes 5MB + 5mb + 3mb(at least) = **13mb**(at least) of ram to store a 5mb XML file . . . and that's not counting bytes lost to memory alignment, or the extra bytes used to store the size of each string object `**`.

Also consider that because you're caching the XML document, all those objects immediately become generation 2 collectible objects, which basically means the GC will be **very** lazy about walking that considerable heap to see what it can collect.

See [Rico Mariani's When to call GC.Collect()](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx) for the situations where it's not only OK to call GC Collect, but when it's necessary to call it.

Hope this helps, sorry if I'm preaching to the choir on the memory size thing.

`*` I've no idea if this is actually the case, but would be surprised if it isn't.
`**` I'm assuming .net strings store the size of the string before/after the actual characters of the string, this could significantly increase the in-memory representation by and extra 4-8 bytes per node, giving at 20 byte cost per 20 bytes of node name/value. Which effectively increases the overhead to match the size of the data stored.

Answer (score 1):

Since aggressive GCing cleans things up you should be looking for places where you may not be disposing objects that implement `IDisposable`.  Perhaps you need to look at your code using the XSL Transform to be sure that objects used there are properly disposed.